# Video Preview before Upload is not working in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Goal**: Trying to upload a video to the server and display the video preview before the upload.
**Bug**:The video preview is working fine for the **first time** but when I try to upload the video again the **new video** preview does not display and but the old video keeps on playing.

**My Code**: I have a state `videoPreview` and I am using it as a source to my video tag source. The `setVideoPreview` is set to the uploaded file. This only works the first time but if I upload the video again it does not get rerendered again and the preview of the previous video keeps on playing. Here is my code snippet

```js
 <label for="videos">
              
                
                  <video
                    width="400"
                    height="150"
                    style={{ height: "143px", objectFit: "contain" }}
                    autoPlay
                    loop
                  >
                    <source src={videoPreview} />
                  </video>
                
              
            </label>
            <input
              type="file"
              id="videos"
              accept="video/*"
              className="text-transparent -ml-52"
              
              onChange={(e) => {
                const files = e.target.files;
                let myFiles = Array.from(files);

                const fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = () => {
                  if (fileReader.readyState === 2) {
                    formik.setFieldValue("video", myFiles);
                    setVideoPreview(fileReader.result);//this is my state
                  }
                };
                if (e.target.files[0]) {
                  fileReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
                }
              }}
              value={formik.values.video.name}
            />
```

I have no idea why the state is not updating or if it's updating the preview is not changing.

Comment: Is the `videoPreview` actually updating? Is its value changing? Can you provide a more complete and comprehensive code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I was able to solve the bug via the `onloadstart` and `onloadend` event listeners of the `FileReader` object. I set the `videoPreview` to **null** on the `onloadstart` and to the `FileReader.result` on  the `onloadend`. 
Here is the code I used in the onChange function

```js
onChange={(e) => {
                  const files = e.target.files;

                  let myFiles = Array.from(files);

                  const fileReader = new FileReader();

                  fileReader.onload = () => {
                    if (fileReader.readyState === 2) {
                      formik.setFieldValue("video", myFiles);
                    }
                  };
                  fileReader.onloadstart = () => {
                    setVideoPreview(null);
                  };
                  fileReader.onloadend = () => {
                    setVideoPreview(fileReader.result);
                  };
                  if (e.target.files[0]) {
                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
                  }
                }}
```